# Get Monthly Totals from Running Totals

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in a SQL Server 2008 database with two columns that hold running totals called Hours and Starts. Another column, Date, holds the date of a record. The dates are sporadic throughout any given month, but there's always a record for the last hour of the month.

For example:

```
ContainerID | Date             | Hours | Starts

1           | 2010-12-31 23:59 | 20    | 6
1           | 2011-01-15 00:59 | 23    | 6
1           | 2011-01-31 23:59 | 30    | 8

2           | 2010-12-31 23:59 | 14    | 2
2           | 2011-01-18 12:59 | 14    | 2
2           | 2011-01-31 23:59 | 19    | 3
```

How can I query the table to get the total number of hours and starts for each month between two specified years? (In this case 2011 and 2013.) I know that I need to take the values from the last record of one month and subtract it by the values from the last record of the previous month. I'm having a hard time coming up with a good way to do this in SQL, however.

As requested, here are the expected results:

```
ContainerID | Date             | MonthlyHours | MonthlyStarts
1           | 2011-01-31 23:59 | 10           | 2
2           | 2011-01-31 23:59 | 5            | 1
```

Comment: 29:59? an extra 6 hours in the day would be nice.

Comment: Can you add expected results for above example?

Comment: No joke... I corrected the typo.

Comment: You also have, what I presume is typo, in 3rd row - `ContainerID = 2` ?

Comment: Yes, I corrected it and added what I would expect from the example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using [recursive CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and some 'creative' JOIN condition, you can fetch next month's value for each ContainterID:

```
WITH CTE_PREP AS 
(
    --RN will be 1 for last row in each month for each container 
    --MonthRank will be sequential number for each subsequent month (to increment easier)
    SELECT 
        *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ContainerID, YEAR(Date), MONTH(DATE) ORDER BY Date DESC) RN
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY YEAR(Date),MONTH(Date)) MonthRank
    FROM Table1
)
, RCTE AS 
(
    --"Zero row", last row in decembar 2010 for each container
    SELECT *, Hours AS MonthlyHours, Starts AS MonthlyStarts
    FROM CTE_Prep
    WHERE YEAR(date) = 2010 AND MONTH(date) = 12 AND RN = 1 

    UNION ALL

    --for each next row just join on MonthRank + 1
    SELECT t.*, t.Hours - r.Hours, t.Starts - r.Starts
    FROM RCTE r
    INNER JOIN CTE_Prep t ON r.ContainerID = t.ContainerID AND r.MonthRank + 1 = t.MonthRank AND t.Rn = 1
)
SELECT ContainerID, Date, MonthlyHours, MonthlyStarts
FROM RCTE
WHERE Date >= '2011-01-01' --to eliminate "zero row"
ORDER BY ContainerID
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca43d/2)** (I have added some data for February and March in order to test on different lengths of months)

[Old version fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca43d/1)

Comment: Since this works with your SQLFiddle demo I'm marking it as the answer. It would have worked for me, but I found that the data is messy to different degrees across the different containers (e.g. some containers having duplicate records, inconsistent month-end times) making it unfeasible to get what I need through a SQL query.

Comment: @Matt I can rewrite the query to make it always use the last record in each month disregarding of actual time and duplicates - if that can help you?

Comment: @Matt OK. I have edited the answer with new version. This is a better solution anyway then using that last minute of month. I don't know why I haven't thought of it in the first place.

Comment: What comes in my mind - if there are months with no data for container - query might need some tweaking to count them as 0.

Comment: it would make much more sense to disregard months where there is no info from previous month.

Comment: @Nenad I ran this overnight and it hadn't finished by this morning. There are over 7 million rows in this table. Is this problematic for a recursive CTE?

Comment: 7 million rows can be problematic for many things including recursive CTE. However recursion here occurs over months, so there shouldn't be that many levels of recursion. I guess ROW_NUMBER() and DENSE_RANK() also took their time here and using them from CTE might be a killer.

Comment: Here are some suggestions to try and speed things up. First make sure to filter all unnecessary data in CTE_Prep, don't let it work for months you don't need (older then dec2010 ie). Then instead of using CTE_Prep in query directly, you can maybe run that query separately, see how long it takes and select from CTE_Prep into temp table - only rows with RN=1 (if there aren't a millions of them?). Then edit RCTE to use temp table instead of CTE_Prep. Maybe even create an index on temp table (cluster on RN, ContainerID, MonthRank)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  c1.ContainerID, 
        c1.Date, 
        c1.Hours-c3.Hours AS "MonthlyHours", 
        c1.Starts - c3.Starts AS "MonthlyStarts"
FROM Containers c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Containers c2 ON
                                c1.ContainerID = c2.ContainerID
                            AND datediff(MONTH, c1.Date, c2.Date)=0
                            AND c2.Date > c1.Date
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Containers c3 ON
                                    c1.ContainerID = c3.ContainerID
                                AND datediff(MONTH, c1.Date, c3.Date)=-1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Containers c4 ON
                                    c3.ContainerID = c4.ContainerID
                                AND datediff(MONTH, c3.Date, c4.Date)=0
                                AND c4.Date > c3.Date
    WHERE 
            c2.ContainerID is null
        AND c4.ContainerID is null
        AND c3.ContainerID is not null
ORDER BY c1.ContainerID, c1.Date
```